# Cannot access app if logged user is blocked in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add code to my app if logged user is blocked or not if the user is blocked then he cannot access my app and send to a new activity 
please help. How it possible using Firebase?

Comment: Show your code first. What is the error?

Comment: onStart() method

Comment: I thought only about it, I am not created

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. You need to implement something first and ask here about errors.

Comment: I have not found any tutorial about this, so I asked here

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth Research first before asking a question SO.

Comment: I have research about it I cannot find my solution

Comment: how i do that in my app is very simple , i just add a value in my firebase databse, lets say , expired = 0  , so inside my app i have an authlistener that is hearing if the user is logged in, if the user is logged in and expired == 0 i let the user use the app, if the user is connected and expired == 1 i do an intent to another activity where the user is blocked, if he wants to enter again the listener will send him back always to the expired activity

Comment: Gaston Saillen can you show me your code, please

Comment: yes i will, but you need to have at least the knowladge of firebase authlisteners

Comment: I have small knowledge about firebase authlisteners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I manage to block an user in my app. The logic is simple, first I just check for a data inside the database; if that data is 0 or 1 I do something with that value. Here I'm just getting that value and doing something with it, in my app works great to block users who never paid:

```
private int mIntPaid;

private void myBlockMethod{


     if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null){
    
            final DatabaseReference paidRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Paid");
    
            paidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshotPaid) {
    
            mIntPaid = Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshotPaid.getValue().toString());
    
    //And then just check if that value is 0 or 1 to send the user to the block activity
    
          if (mIntPaid == 0) {
                                                //continue using app 
    {else if (mIntPaid == 1) {
    //app block
                                                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, ExpiredLicence.class);
                                                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                                                        finish();
        }
    
    
    }
}
```

Just call this method in oncreate `myBlockMethod()`, so every time a user opens the app it will check for the values in Firebase. If they are different, the if statement will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a database with all the users and if the user is blocked you update a table called `User_blocked` so you will code a statement to check whether or not the user is blocked or not. Please not we cant give you answers like this if you do not show us some sort of code because this is not a site where we do all the work for you.

Comment: ok thanks bro i will try